# Postgresql 9.3 Replica archive folder files kept on adding in master server

Tags: postgresql

After completed streaming replication in my master server the archive folder size is increasing continuously in my master server. it is taking whole system space, how can i fix this issue in master server not in the slave server.

Comment: 9.3 is out of support. First thing you should do is upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Why are you archiving in the first place?

Comment: i am using streaming replication so i configured in my master archive_mode = on and archive_command= 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/postgresversion/main/archive/%f’